# Алгоритмы обработки движений при помощи датчиков (гироскоп, акселерометр)

Tags: ios, android, java, objective-c

Привет %username%! Нужна твоя помощь.

Я разобрался как работать с датчиками, как получать с них данные, но на этом все.
Я перерыл много просторов интернета, но так и не нашел нужной информации. Возможно у кого то есть какие то наработки или должные знания.
Суть следующая. Как при помощи датчиков обрабатывать движения: прыжок, шаг, приседания, др?
Каков алгоритм действий?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

А в чём проблема?

Мы лично в играх нормируем показание датчиков, в итоге по всем осям значения в промежутке от 0 до 1.

В зависимости от этого что-то делаем. К примеру, есть у вас MAX скорость, она соответствует 1. 0.5 с датчика = 0.5 от MAX. И т.д. Это если линейно.

Главное - нормировать показания, а дальше проблем вроде как быть не должно.

Comment: ну это немного нето.
В играх вы же наверняка отслеживали, например, наклоны девайса.
В Моем же случае, интересно, как понять что это например, шаг, или прыжок?

Comment: Если меняется по оси X, то движение. Если по Y, то приседание/прыжок.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я так понял, имеется в виду более высокий уровень абстракции. Допустим, у нас есть только скорость. -0.1 по y это уже приседание или просто погрешность? Как лучше поступить, накапливать сумму скорость*время и таким образом вычислять координаты и, допустим, больше -30 см по y - приседание?

Comment: @Михаил М да это уже кто как хочет. В идеале надо учитывать прошлую скорость, вычислять новую на её основе, а потом уже менять координаты.